# How to draw UML to illustrate 2 threads working on a critical section

Tags: c++, multithreading, uml, mutex

I have a small program that runs 2 threads on the same critical section and uses mutex. The program works fine. But I would like to draw a UML, referably activity or state diagram, illustrating that the 2 threads runs the same critical section, not different parts of the codes. Please help me revise my UML.

Below is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdio.h>
/* Global variables where both threads have access to*/
std::mutex myMutex;
int globalVariable = 1;
/* CRITICAL SECTION */
void hello()
{
    myMutex.lock();
    for (int counter =0 ; counter< 100; counter++){
        //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
        printf("%d ",std::this_thread::get_id() );      //print the id of the thread that executes the for loop
        globalVariable++;
    }
    printf("Thread with id = %d runs. Counter is %d \n", std::this_thread::get_id(), msg) ; //print the result counter value and thread id that finishes the for loop
    myMutex.unlock();
}
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(hello);
    std::thread t2(hello);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
```

Below is my UML. It definitely has some faults
[image]

Comment: I just failed with an answer (using an AD), but anyhow I would like to suggest that a State Machine would probably the best to describe that concurrency. Coming up with a good example is hard for me since it's not really my expertise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It definitely has some faults

yes, for instance :

- both *join* finish *before* the execution of *hello*, this is impossible
- each *join* are executed in one the separated threads, this must be done by *main*
- there is a *fork* but no *join* (the UML one)
- after the action *unlock* the flow goes to *t2.join* which is false and produces a  never ending loop

---

In a sequence diagram it is possible to use a *combined fragment critical*, but there is no specific notation in an activity to indicate a critical region.

A first possibility is to not try to indicate the critical section, to use *call operation actions* on the mutex to call *lock* and *unlock*, and the reader has to know what that means. You can also add a note to help the reader. For instance (the call to *hello* is replaced by its body and I replaced the loop by an opaque action to simplify) :

[image]

Or with the partition :

[image]

A second way is to use a *combined fragment critical* even this is not specified in the norm, hoping the reader understand ( may be with the help of a note ) :

[image]

Of course you can combine using the first way and also drawing the *combined fragment critical* hoping to help the reader :

[image]

A third way if you do not want to have actions corresponding to C++ is to emulate the critical region using accept/send signal action, but to be frank this is not really easy to read/understand :

[image]

or with the partition :

[image]

Of course it is also possible to do the first send signal action after the *fork* :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not straightforward to represent this situation in UML (not an expert here).

After seeing Bruno's answer, I remembered Petri Nets. From that, I supposed  someone have devised a composed solution. And, indeed:

- Baresi, L. and Pezze, M., 2001. Improving UML with Petri nets. Electronic
  Notes in Theoretical Computer Science, 44(4), pp.107-119.

I point the article here because I'm unable to summarize it in a single diagram or short explanation (you know the saying, "*traduttore traditore*").

Assuming UML is a requisite (company/team rules) I'd dare represent the solution both ways: by means of UML, based on ideas as bruno's and studies like the one cited; and also by a Petri Net diagram (an appendix in the documentation would hardly do any harm, or would it?).

Comment: could you please add a link to referred article?